# Allow App In Android Emulator to Access Intranet

Tags: android, emulation, intranet

This probably has been asked a hundred times.  But I can't seem to see any answer.  How do I set the Android emulator so that my app running in it can access a web server set up in our intranet (LAN)?

I have tried setting the proxy/port (both in the settings in Android and specifying -http-proxy when launching the emulator) but I can't get my app to connect to the intranet.

Hopefully, someone can give me a quick answer as this is really urgent.

Thanks and regards,
Rai

Comment: Personally, I didn't have to do anything - the internet simply worked since the computer running the emulator had it. Perhaps your app can't connect to the internet as you didn't request the internet permission?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add any new configuration to the emulator to work. It uses the network what your laptop or System has. It is a new bridge setup on your system using which it communicates to the outside world.

So, I suggest, you check if your system is able to connect to the web server is setup.